# NameError: global name is not defined

Tags: python

I know there are a bunch of similar questions, but they didn't help me to understand my problem. Also I have 3 modules:

First one is `model`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elixir import *
from run_test import create_db
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint
class ValueTest(Test): 
    value = Field(Integer)
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.name = name;
        self.value = value
```

If I run the test method from the second module named `run_test`, there aren't any problems

```
from model import *
def main():
    test();
def test():
    test = ValueTest("test",2)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I try something like that, I get the the well known error `NameError: global name 'ValueTest' is not defined`

```
import run_test
def main():
    run_test.test()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>When you import a module, you don't import the names it has imported; you only import the names it defines itself.  You still need to do `from model import ValueTest` in the last script.</s>

If `from foo import *` imported every name that `foo` imported into its own scope, a single `import something` might also import every symbol in `os` or `sys` for example.  It would be a nightmare.

---

Actually, this is not true.  The symbols imported from the module are only those defined by the `__all__` list set in that module.  (If not present, all symbols not starting with `_` are indeed imported.)

Thanks Ethan for the correction.

Comment: following the http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki/TutorialDivingIn elixir tutorial, I had to import the whole elixir module in module 1(model). In module 2(run_test) by running session.commit()(It's not in the example) i persist the model. When I import model by using "from model import ValueTest" in the second module, the session.commit()(elixir) isn't visible

Comment: okay after reading couple of times your answer, I finally managed to see where I was wrong. Thank you ! :)

Comment: This is wrong.  `from somemodule import *` will import either 1) all objects listed in `somemodule.__all__`; or, if `__all__` is not defined by `somemodule`, __everything__ in `somemodule` that does not begin with a leading `_` -- it does __not__ matter where it came from.

Comment: Indeed that is true; I was mistaken.  I've verified this using a simple three-module test on my machine.

Comment: You're welcome.  Your answer isn't actually answering his question though.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you have circular imports happening.  `run_test` is importing `model`, which in turn is importing `run_test`.  Strange things happen when circular imports are used.  If you can, put the common functions (`create_db`, in your example) into another module, then `model` can import it from there and not from `run_test`.